# Perlin noise infinite generation/tiling?

Tags: random, perlin-noise

I got the Perlin Noise algorithm from [Here](http://devmag.org.za/2009/04/25/perlin-noise/) working, and I was wondering if there was a way to make the terrain infinite.  The problem lies within this function(Java):

```
float[][] GenerateWhiteNoise(int width, int height, int seed)
    {
        Random random;
        random = new Random(seed);
        float[][] noise = new float[width][height];
     
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                noise[i][j] = (float)random.nextDouble() % 1;
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("Generated White Noise with seed:"+seed+"; xOffset:"+xOffset+"; yOffset:"+yOffset);
     
        return noise;
    }
```

Does anyone know how to make the random generator for this function rely on the offset of the current tile of noise(these are stored in two variables, `xOffset` and `yOffset`)?  Using something like `Math.pow(xOffset,yOffset)` and setting that as the seed produced choppy, broken results that simply don't work.  Does anybody have some insight?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: There are several good answers in this question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23625/how-do-you-generate-tileable-perlin-noise

Answer (score 0):

Here's tiling 4D noise implemented in a GLSL shader:

http://shaderfrog.com/app/view/254

It's based on the implementation in this answer https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23625/how-do-you-generate-tileable-perlin-noise/23639